# Div around image not resizing in flexbox

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get images in a **flexbox** to risize properly, which they do. However, these images have an *overlaying* image, so I create a div in which the image and the overlay reside. However, this div *does not properly scale with the images*. It looks like this: (I added a lightblue background color to one of the divs for demonstration purposes).

[image: Wronly sized divs around an image]

All of this is inside of a containing div. The HTML and CSS look like this:

```css
.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.imagecontainer {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.image {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    max-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="imagecontainer">
    <img src="image" class="image">
    <img src="overlay" class="image">
  </div>
  <div class="imagecontainer">
    <img src="image2" class="image">
    <img src="overlay2" class="image">
  </div>
</div>
```

Now my question is, how do I get the `imagecontainer` as wide as the images inside of it? I've tried numerous things but nothing seems to be working the way I want it to..

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Together with [@MrSegFaulty](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9724628/mrsegfaulty) 's answer, I additionally had to add `height: max-content` to the `container` class and specify `max-width: 100%` to both image and overlaty. The final result looks like this:

```css
.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    width: 100%;
    height: max-content;
}

.imagecontainer {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
}

.image, .overlay {
    max-height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%
}

.overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="imagecontainer">
    <img src="image.jpg" class="image">
    <img src="overlay.jpg" class="overlay">
  </div>
  <div class="imagecontainer">
    <img src="image2.jpg" class="image">
    <img src="overlay2.jpg" class="overlay">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Awesome, that my answer helped you. Just want to point out the limited support of `height: max-content` in MS browsers and Safari [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-css_properties_height_max-content)

Comment: I didn't know about that, thanks for pointing it out! I'll have a closer look at it!

Answer (score 1):

Hope the following helps. I removed `position: absolute;` from first image in `.imagecontainer` so that this image will not be taken out of the normal layout flow. Also, removed `width: 100%;` from `.imagecontainer`.

```css
.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.imagecontainer {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
}

.image, .overlay {
    max-height: 100%;
}

.overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="imagecontainer">
    <img src="image.jpg" class="image">
    <img src="overlay.jpg" class="overlay">
  </div>
  <div class="imagecontainer">
    <img src="image2.jpg" class="image">
    <img src="overlay2.jpg" class="overlay">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This solution solves the issue I was having but it breaks the scaling of the images. Now they stay their original size instead of scaling with the flexbox